# Laravel: Get id from database in controller and update data

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to get the id from the $client and send the id to insert it into the database.

```
 $client = DB::table('clients')->where('product_id', '=', $request->get('product'))->get();
 $invoice = new Invoice();
 $invoice->total = ($request->get('subscription'))*1.15;
 $invoice->client_id = //get id from $client;
 $invoice->save();
```

$client = [{"id":23,"name":"testname","product_id":678}]

Anyone have an idea how to get id from $client?

Comment: You are always  trying to generate  invoice for first client for same product. Lets consider the scenario `$client = [{"id":23,"name":"testname","product_id":678},{"id":24,"name":"testname2","product_id":678}]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. how can you get the last inserted id. Now it gives the first id that means "id"=23

Comment: you can get max id from client table, but it is also not bound. you have to change other way.

Comment: what do you mean other way?

Comment: I mean you have ensure that all bunch of transaction works if not then none will execute you can use `DB::transactions` to `commit` and `rollback`. I guess you are executing multiple transactions, `user order`, `order status`, `invoice` these all must be bind each other. only getting last id or max id will not sure that it is going right. Hope this is enough to understand.  Happy Navratri .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$client = DB::table('clients')
            ->where('product_id', '=', $request->get('product'))
            ->first();
 $invoice = new Invoice();
 $invoice->total = ($request->get('subscription'))*1.15;
 $invoice->client_id = $client->id;
 $invoice->save();
```

Comment: that for your Answer. simple first instead of get

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value` method of query builder this will work fine have a look:

```
      $client = DB::table('clients')
         ->where('product_id', '=', $request->get('product'))
         ->value('id');
         $invoice = new Invoice();
         $invoice->total = ($request->get('subscription'))*1.15;
         $invoice->client_id = $client;
         $invoice->save();
```

Or `First` of method query builder:

```
$client = DB::table('clients')
             ->where('product_id', '=', $request->get('product'))
             ->first();
             $invoice = new Invoice();
             $invoice->total = ($request->get('subscription'))*1.15;
             $invoice->client_id = $client->id;
             $invoice->save();
```